# Not able to run "find" query in remote mongodb collection using MongoClient in Node.js application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path    = require("path");
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  format = require('util').format;
var uri = 'mongodb://ac-00072810.devapollogrp.edu:27017/devdb';

MongoClient.connect(uri,function(err,db){

    db.collection('TransactionStatus',function(err,collection){

        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        else{
            collection.find({}).forEach(function(err,doc){
                console.log(doc);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Getting Error:

```
[apol@ac-00067394 nodejs-testapp]$ node Server.js
body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded 
middlewares Server.js:15:9
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option 
node_modules/body-parser/index.js:105:29
Running at Port 3001
undefined
```

(Note: mongodb version:3.0.2,node version:0.12.7, express version:4.12.4)

From mongo shell I am able to get all the details successfully. But when I am trying to fetch data using mongoClient form the application getting error "undefined". I tried all possibilities. But I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help  :)

Comment: Please format your code and mention the actual errors or results you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance it looks like you're getting the `[forEach][1]` behaviour wrong. The callback passed to `forEach` accepts three params: currentValue, index and array, respectively, since it's a core Javascript function and not Node-specific (which is why you probably followed the `err`, `doc` convention).

Try this in the `else` block:

```
collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docArray){
    console.log(docArray);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Yes forEach was the culprit, again thanks for clarifying the behavior of forEach. It's really great help for me. I will be looking forward to get more advice from you in future.

Comment: No problem. You can accept the answer if it resolved your issue.